# Running AddAdGroupBidModifier.java from Adwords returns Axisfault

Tags: java, google-ads-api

I am trying to the run the AddAdGroupBidModifier.java using my test account credentials as below; i have replaced the key credentials with xxxx

```
api.adwords.email=sxxxxxxn@gmail.com
api.adwords.password=xxxxxxxxxxx
api.adwords.clientCustomerId=5xx-xxx-xx63
api.adwords.userAgent=SXXXXXXX
api.adwords.developerToken=Hxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxw
api.adwords.isPartialFailure=false
api.adwords.returnMoneyInMicros=true
api.adwords.clientId=4xxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
api.adwords.clientSecret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
api.adwords.refreshToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The code i am running is

```
public class AddAdGroupBidModifier {

  private static final double BID_MODIFIER = 2.5;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Generate a refreshable OAuth2 credential similar to a ClientLogin token
    // and can be used in place of a service account.
    Credential oAuth2Credential = new OfflineCredentials.Builder()
        .forApi(Api.ADWORDS)
        .fromFile("C:\\Users\\devrajg\\workspace\\MovieDB\\web\\properties\\ads.properties")
        .build()
        .generateCredential();

    // Construct an AdWordsSession.
    AdWordsSession session = new AdWordsSession.Builder()
        .fromFile("C:\\Users\\devrajg\\workspace\\MovieDB\\web\\properties\\ads.properties")
        .withOAuth2Credential(oAuth2Credential)
        .build();

    //Long adGroupId = Long.valueOf("INSERT_ADGROUP_ID_HERE");
    Long adGroupId = 17176964687L;

    AdWordsServices adWordsServices = new AdWordsServices();

    runExample(adWordsServices, session, adGroupId);
  }
```

This did run once and i was able to modify the Bid for a AdGroup successfully (as seen by the print in code).

But when trying to run again i keep getting the below error; stack pasted

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server
 faultSubcode:
 faultString: [CriterionError.BID_MODIFIER_ALREADY_EXISTS @ operations[0].operand.criterion; trigger:'AdGroupId AdGroupId: 17176964687, CriterionId CriterionId{id=30001}']
 faultActor:
 faultNode:
 faultDetail:
    {https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201409}ApiExceptionFault:<message>[CriterionError.BID_MODIFIER_ALREADY_EXISTS @ operations[0].operand.criterion; trigger:'AdGroupId AdGroupId: 17176964687, CriterionId CriterionId{id=30001}']</message><ApplicationException.Type>ApiException</ApplicationException.Type><errors xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="CriterionError"><fieldPath>operations[0].operand.criterion</fieldPath><trigger>AdGroupId AdGroupId: 17176964687, CriterionId CriterionId{id=30001}</trigger><errorString>CriterionError.BID_MODIFIER_ALREADY_EXISTS</errorString><ApiError.Type>CriterionError</ApiError.Type><reason>BID_MODIFIER_ALREADY_EXISTS</reason></errors>

[CriterionError.BID_MODIFIER_ALREADY_EXISTS @ operations[0].operand.criterion; trigger:'AdGroupId AdGroupId: 17176964687, CriterionId CriterionId{id=30001}']
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializer.<init>(BeanDeserializer.java:104)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializer.<init>(BeanDeserializer.java:90)
    at com.google.api.ads.adwords.axis.v201409.cm.ApiException.getDeserializer(ApiException.java:143)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BaseDeserializerFactory.getSpecialized(BaseDeserializerFactory.java:154)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BaseDeserializerFactory.getDeserializerAs(BaseDeserializerFactory.java:84)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.getDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:464)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.getDeserializerForType(DeserializationContext.java:547)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultDetailsBuilder.onStartChild(SOAPFaultDetailsBuilder.java:157)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(DeserializationContext.java:1035)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:796)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.google.api.ads.adwords.axis.v201409.cm.AdGroupBidModifierServiceSoapBindingStub.mutate(AdGroupBidModifierServiceSoapBindingStub.java:739)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Has anyone seen this?

Thanks,
-Devraj

Comment: An Update; this was fixed with a SET Operator as the ADD already succeeded.

Comment: please create an answer with the details of what you did to resolve this. Then accept your own answer. This will help other people with the same problem in the future!

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by using the SET operator as the ADD was already done once. The key was the error "BID_MODIFIER_ALREADY_EXISTS"

Thanks,
-Devraj